# If statement on a number and it's multipliers

Tags: php, for-loop, if-statement, multiplication

I want to make a loop that works in 2 ways , if period is anynumber but 13 and it's multiplications , it will call the last income I had , if not it should make the equations you see below , any idea how to ?

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $period ; $i++) { 
         if ($i+=13) {
         echo round($income=$income*(1+($rowage/100))). "<br>";
         } else
         {
        echo $income. "<br>";
         }
    }
```

Comment: `if ($period % 13 == 0)` ?

Comment: When stuck, don't try to do lots of operations on one line...

Comment: Not working , I keep getting the initial income and counts it for all the period

Comment: @David worked when I used if ($i % 13 ==0), thanks for the tip :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called mutiple of 13, and you can use modulos:

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $period ; $i++) { 
     if ($i%13==0) {
     echo round($income=$income*(1+($rowage/100))). "<br>";
     } else
     {
    echo $income. "<br>";
     }
}
```

$i%13==0 means if division of i by 13 gives 0, which should be true if i is multiple of 13.